# While loop php arrays

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, while-loop

I have three php arrays that i am filling up with information returned from a msql query.  The first two arrays fill up perfectly with the information need but the last array does not fill up. The only thing that gets entered is a 'v'.  It works perfectly if i don't make it an array and just a single value but when i make it an array it stops working. If you have any ideas thanks.

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM chanels WHERE cname = '$cname' ");
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
    $videolocation[$counter2] = $row['videolocation'];
    $title[$counter2] = $row['title'];
    $imagelocation[$counter2] =  $row['videoimagelocation'];
    $counter2++;

}
```

ImageLocation array is the one that does not work while the other two fill up perfectly. I have checked spelling and everything is entered perfectly.

Comment: What is `$counter2`? Also you could use a single array to store all three values. Why use 3 arrays?

Comment: Use `var_dump` to show us the content of `$row` in the last case. Second, please don't use `mysql_*` functions, it's [*deprecated (see red box)*](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) and vulnerable to sql-injection. Use PDO or MySQLi.

Comment: check print_r($row); contains this key videoimagelocation ?

Comment: $counter2 = 0 and it used as index values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `fetch_array` use [mysql_fetch_assoc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php) for your method so that you bring back the rows with keys in the array named as the columns in the results - like this:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $row["videolocation"];
    echo $row["title"];
    echo $row["videoimagelocation"];
}
```

Also, you should probably move away from the old `mysql_*` functions and tinker with the new shiny [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) functions. These will let you connect in a much safer manner as well as providing much more flexibility.

Edit: When you bring back an assoc array, it is still a single row of the database. However, your current code returns something like this:

```
$row[0]='someLoc' // Data from videoLocation
$row[1]='someTitle' // Data from title column
$row[2]='someImageLoc' // Data from videoImageLocation
```

And Assoc Array will work like this:

```
$row['videolocation']='someLoc' 
$row['title']='someTitle' 
$row['videoimagelocation]='someImageLoc'
```

Edit 2: It seems that I chased down a bit of a red herring with the array vs assoc issue. The first thing that I could check is the spelling, but you have done that, the next is check the *case* of the column names. On windows, the case is by default not important, but on Linux machines it *is*.

I find the easiest way is to do this:

```
mysql_query("SELECT videolocation, title, videoimagelocation FROM chanels WHERE cname = '$cname' ");
```

If a column is the wrong case, this should return an error for you.

Comment: I am trying to add these values into arrays and the reason i am fetching arrays is because the query may return more than one row

Comment: @Fluffeh When you use `mysql_fetch_array()` with no second argument, it defaults to `MYSQL_BOTH`, so the returned array contains __both__ the numeric indexes and the string indexes.

Comment: Thank you can you please vote my question up cause I don't want to get a bad rep

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, but a suggestion to make better use of arrays. Use a single one to store all data:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
    $details[$counter2] = array('videoLocation' => $row['videolocation'],
                                'title' =>   $row['title'],
                                'imageLocation' => $row['videoimagelocation']
                                );
    $counter++;
}
```

That way, first index will store 1st row details, second index will store 2nd row details and so on.